# Are tags that have nothing to do with islam ok?

Tags: discussion

The currently most popular question, "[Can Allah create a rock that He can't lift?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11966/can-allah-create-a-rock-that-he-cant-lift)" has been newly tagged with "[omnipotence-paradox](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omnipotence-paradox)", which actually has nothing to do with islam/objective-of-this-site.

Are these tags ok to be created?